# How can I remove relationship between entities in EF6 code-first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have one-to-many relationship between objects A and B.

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
    public B Owner { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<A> OwnedObjects { get; set; }
}
```

i have

```
AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

I want to delete A from OwnedObjects but not from database.

this:

```
var b = Bs.Find(id);
Entry(b).Collection(_=>_.OwnedObjects).Load();
var someObjToRemove = b.OwnedObjects[0];
b.OwnedObjects.Remove(someObjToRemove);
Entry(b).State = EntityState.Modified;
SaveChanges();
```

doesn't help

this:

```
var b = Bs.Find(id);
Entry(b).Collection(_=>_.OwnedObjects).Load();
var someObjToRemove = b.OwnedObjects[0];
someObjToRemove.OwnerId = null;
Entry(someObjToRemove).State = EntityState.Modified;
SaveChanges();
```

throws exception:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'B.Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'A.OwnerId' on the other end.

I can't delete object A and create another one without Owner because there is many other objects related with A

It's seems to be not so hard to do. But I can't find any solution

Comment: Reviewing this a bit more, I think the problem with the second option is that you need to load `A` and mark it as modified before EF can update both halves of the relationship.  But I don't have a reliable way to test it right this second.

Comment: someObjToRemove it is instance of an A. Entry(someObjToRemove).State = EntityState.Modified; and marked Modified. and I can add Entry(b).State = EntityState.Modified; but it changes nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Only solution i found it's to call `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` after adding or removing items.

```
var itemToAdd = As.Find(a1.Id);
b.OwnedObjects.Add(itemToAdd);

var itemToRemove = As.Find(a2.Id);
b.OwnedObjects.Remove(itemToRemove);

ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
SaveChanges();
```

works great. but ChangeTracker.Entries() contains **only** instances of `A` modified. And if I replace `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` by

```
Entry(itemToAdd).State = EntityState.Modified; 
Entry(itemToRemove).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

it doesn't work again.

So i think, calling `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` it is most simplest way to solve this problem